# PostgresQL installation issues

Tags: postgresql, installation

I already knew I wasn't good at db stuff, postgres went and reminded me.

I'm trying to install postgresQL on my machine.  I've been following the docs, which are extremely thorough but I've run into a blocker that I can't get past.  I'm on section [1.3 of the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-createdb.html) where we run `createdb mydb`.  I get `command not found` on my machine.  Ok. That's fine, the docs mention that.  I move on to using the direct path for the the `createdb` command which is found at /usr/local/pgsql/bin/createdb on my machine and run it there.  I get the next docs error:

```
createdb: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
```

Ok.......Well now I'm told to just look through the installation docs.  I'm not able to find anything relating to my situation in there.  I'm a n00b at this stuff so you can talk dumb to me, that'd be great.

Peace love and honk honk

Answer (score 0):

Check if the server is running. If not, start it using `pg_ctl` as documented. If the server is running, check the `unix_socket_directories` parameter in `postgersql.conf`. Make sure to use the `psql` you built. If in doubt, uninstall all other PostgreSQL software.

Comment: Understand that my familiarity with this sort of work is elementary at best, probably worse.  I don't know what `pg_ctl` is or does nor where to find it, and I don't see that in the docs as it relates to installation.  I cannot locate my `postgresql.conf` as it relates to this install (i have other postgresql.conf files on my machine from work projects, those are containerized; does that even matter?), nor do i know what to be looking for when I do find it.

Comment: Well, that is the point where a computer programmer starts reading the documentation. Or you go hire someone who does the work for you.